# Can't launch TMXTiledMapExample

Tags: android, andengine

I've just installed andengine from 0. I had to spend 2 days on it. A lot of problems and really bad tutorials with incomplete info. Finally it works, except the example I need, all is working. I have all extensions downloaded and loaded on project. 
I'm using [this](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineTMXTiledMapExtension) extension. All other examples, or many of them are working. Backgrounds>Using a TMXTiledMap is crashing.

Here's the log file from logcat

```
06-15 01:10:33.153: E/dalvikvm(28675): Could not find class 'org.andengine.extension.tmx.TMXLoader', referenced from method org.andengine.examples.TMXTiledMapExample.onCreateScene
06-15 01:10:33.153: W/dalvikvm(28675): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1050 (Lorg/andengine/extension/tmx/TMXLoader;) in Lorg/andengine/examples/TMXTiledMapExample;
06-15 01:10:33.153: D/dalvikvm(28675): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x000f
06-15 01:10:33.153: W/dalvikvm(28675): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 1054 (Lorg/andengine/extension/tmx/util/exception/TMXLoadException;)
06-15 01:10:33.153: W/dalvikvm(28675): VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0xfb
06-15 01:10:33.153: W/dalvikvm(28675): VFY:  rejected Lorg/andengine/examples/TMXTiledMapExample;.onCreateScene ()Lorg/andengine/entity/scene/Scene;
06-15 01:10:33.153: W/dalvikvm(28675): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x00fb
06-15 01:10:33.153: W/dalvikvm(28675): VFY:  rejected Lorg/andengine/examples/TMXTiledMapExample;.onCreateScene ()Lorg/andengine/entity/scene/Scene;
06-15 01:10:33.153: W/dalvikvm(28675): Verifier rejected class Lorg/andengine/examples/TMXTiledMapExample;
06-15 01:10:33.153: W/dalvikvm(28675): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lorg/andengine/examples/TMXTiledMapExample;)
06-15 01:10:33.153: D/AndroidRuntime(28675): Shutting down VM
06-15 01:10:33.153: W/dalvikvm(28675): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2b542210)
06-15 01:10:33.153: E/AndroidRuntime(28675): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-15 01:10:33.153: E/AndroidRuntime(28675): java.lang.VerifyError: org/andengine/examples/TMXTiledMapExample
06-15 01:10:33.153: E/AndroidRuntime(28675):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
06-15 01:10:33.153: E/AndroidRuntime(28675):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
06-15 01:10:33.153: E/AndroidRuntime(28675):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
06-15 01:10:33.153: E/AndroidRuntime(28675):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1882)
06-15 01:10:33.153: E/AndroidRuntime(28675):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
06-15 01:10:33.153: E/AndroidRuntime(28675):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
06-15 01:10:33.153: E/AndroidRuntime(28675):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
06-15 01:10:33.153: E/AndroidRuntime(28675):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-15 01:10:33.153: E/AndroidRuntime(28675):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-15 01:10:33.153: E/AndroidRuntime(28675):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
06-15 01:10:33.153: E/AndroidRuntime(28675):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-15 01:10:33.153: E/AndroidRuntime(28675):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-15 01:10:33.153: E/AndroidRuntime(28675):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-15 01:10:33.153: E/AndroidRuntime(28675):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-15 01:10:33.153: E/AndroidRuntime(28675):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you checked out the extension from the repository on GitHub (I hope you got AndEngine from there, the other repository on Google Code is severely outdated and GitHub is the new and only home of the engine).

https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/

https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineTMXTiledMapExtension

Answer (score 1):

try to rightclick on your androidproject then go to android, project and add the extensions as references to your project.